# update database based on user input in java

Tags: java, database, jdbc

i'm a new programmer, I was given a task to create a class Subject.java, in which it'll ask the students how many subjects they're taking and then store the subjects information into the database, but the problem with my current code is that only one row is updated in the database. My code is as the following, please help me.

```
                System.out.print("\nEnter number of subject: ");
                int sub = in.nextInt();
                int i=0;

                for (i=0; i<sub; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nCode: ");
                    this.setCode(in.next());

                    System.out.print("\nName: ");
                    this.setName(in.next());

                    System.out.print("\nCredit: ");
                    this.setCredit(in.nextInt());

                // insert into database
                ResultSet rs = null;
                String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO subject (code, name, credit) VALUES (?,?,?)";

                try (Connection conn = MySQLDB.getConnection(); 
                    PreparedStatement pstmt
                        = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);)
                {  

                    // assign parameters for statement
                        pstmt.setString(1, this.getCode());
                        pstmt.setString(2, this.getName());
                        pstmt.setInt (3, this.getCredit());

                        pstmt.addBatch();


                    if (pstmt.executeUpdate() == 1) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nNew subject has been created succesfully!");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nError");
                    }


                } 

                catch (SQLException ex) 
                {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: At the very least, you probably should not close to the `Connection` for every single row, you should open it before the loop and reuse it to insert every row, then execute the update all together.

Comment: i dont get it 

Comment: You do `try (Connection conn = MySQLDB.getConnection();` for every single _row_.  This will connect to the database and close it every single time, so to update 100 rows you are connecting to the database 100 times and closing it 100 times.  Either that or you misplaced your `}`, and it is not in your `for` loop like it appears here.  Post the full method.

Comment: In order to help yourself with programming and debugging, I recommend you refactor your code to follow the principle that each method should be responsible for a single task. So in your case here, I would recommend having one method to run through and collect the user inputs. Once those are collected (for example, in an ArrayList<String>), then run through those inputs and add them to the batch for inserting. This will help you narrow down what is breaking during a debug session much more easily.

Answer (score 2):

As `Nexevis` said , you need to put your `Connection` code outside your `for-loop` like below :

```
// insert into database
 ResultSet rs = null;
 String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO subject (code, name, credit) VALUES (?,?,?)";

 System.out.print("\nEnter number of subject: ");
 int sub = in.nextInt();
 int i = 0;
 try {

     Connection conn = MySQLDB.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement pstmt
         = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

     for (i = 0; i < sub; i++) {
         System.out.print("\nCode: ");
         this.setCode( in.next());

         System.out.print("\nName: ");
         this.setName( in.next());

         System.out.print("\nCredit: ");
         this.setCredit( in.nextInt());

         // assign parameters for statement
         pstmt.setString(1, this.getCode());
         pstmt.setString(2, this.getName());
         pstmt.setInt(3, this.getCredit());
         pstmt.addBatch();
     }
     try {
         // execute it to insert the data
         pstmt.executeBatch();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
         return; // Exit if there was an error
     }
      pstmt.close(); 
      conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
 }
```

Comment: Though the `Connection` should be outside the `for` loop, you should still be using `try-with` resources, as OP did.  It is a much better way to ensure the connection closes properly and is easy to read.